# Is there a boilerplate dApp on Github which uses uPort, truffle and infura on the ropsten testnet?

Tags: truffle, dapps, ropsten, uport

I am developing a dApp using those technologies and facing difficult problems when trying to save information on Ropsten. I can't approve my transaction via uPort because the selected account balance on uPort is 0.

Could anyone post a demo project please?

Comment: Please visit this repository https://github.com/StephenGrider/EthereumCasts Stephen Grider has one course on udemy which source code you can find on his github repo.

Comment: Also, @RaonakIslamNiloy, to get funds on Ropsten just use the [faucet](https://faucet.ropsten.be).

Answer (score 1):

Take a look the truffle box - https://truffleframework.com/boxes/react-uport